# Водяной знак при загрузке всех изображений в ИБ

Tags: php, битрикс

Сайт на битриксе.
Хочу чтобы при загрузке любых изображений в определенные иб ставился водяной знак, вот что написано:

```
<?
AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd",   array("SrWatermark", "OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd"));
AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate",   array("SrWatermark", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate"));

class SrWatermark
{
   function OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd (&$arFields)
   {    
      if($arFields["IBLOCK_ID"] == 14 || $arFields["IBLOCK_ID"] == 15 || $arFields["IBLOCK_ID"] == 16 || $arFields["IBLOCK_ID"] == 17  || $arFields["IBLOCK_ID"] == 18)
      {

         if (strlen($arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["tmp_name"]) > 0)
         {
            $filepath = $arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["tmp_name"];
           $logopath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/i/waterimg.png';

           $watermark = new watermarkImg();

           $watermark->SetLogo($filepath, $logopath);

         }
         if (strlen($arFields["MORE_PHOTO"]["tmp_name"]) > 0)
         {
            $filepath = $arFields["MORE_PHOTO"]["tmp_name"];
           $logopath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/i/waterimg.png';

           $watermark = new watermarkImg();

           $watermark->SetLogo($filepath, $logopath);

         }
      }
   }

   function OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate (&$arFields)
   {
   if($arFields["IBLOCK_ID"] == 14 || $arFields["IBLOCK_ID"] == 15 || $arFields["IBLOCK_ID"] == 16 || $arFields["IBLOCK_ID"] == 17  || $arFields["IBLOCK_ID"] == 18)
      {

         if (strlen($arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["tmp_name"]) > 0)
         {
            $filepath = $arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["tmp_name"];
           $logopath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/i/waterimg.png';

           $watermark = new watermarkImg();

           $watermark->SetLogo($filepath, $logopath);

         }
         if (strlen($arFields["MORE_PHOTO"]["tmp_name"]) > 0)
         {
            $filepath = $arFields["MORE_PHOTO"]["tmp_name"];
           $logopath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/i/waterimg.png';

           $watermark = new watermarkImg();

           $watermark->SetLogo($filepath, $logopath);

         }
      }
   }

}

class watermarkImg  
{  
   function SetLogo($filename, $logo)
   {
      $ar_img = getimagesize($filename);
      if($ar_img["mime"] == 'image/jpeg'){ $srcImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);}
      elseif($ar_img["mime"] == 'image/png'){ $srcImage = ImageCreateFromPNG($filename);}
      elseif($ar_img["mime"] == 'image/gif'){ $srcImage = imagecreatefromgif($filename);}
      else return false;

       $logoImage = ImageCreateFromPNG($logo);

       $srcWidth  = ImageSX($srcImage);
       $srcHeight = ImageSY($srcImage);

       $logoWidth  = ImageSX($logoImage);
       $logoHeight = ImageSY($logoImage);

       imageAlphaBlending($logoImage, false);
       imageSaveAlpha($logoImage, true);

       $trcolor = ImageColorAllocate($logoImage, 255, 255, 255);
       ImageColorTransparent($logoImage , $trcolor);

       imagecopy($srcImage, $logoImage, $srcWidth - $logoWidth,
           $srcHeight - $logoHeight, 0, 0, $logoWidth, $logoHeight);

       ImagePNG($srcImage, $filename);

       ImageDestroy($logoImage);
       ImageDestroy($srcImage);
   }
}  
?>
```

Вот это чудо, не работает почему-то.

Comment: Опишите ошибку-то. Или всем купить битрикс и проверить?)

Comment: Ошибка - водяной знак не накладывается, в чем именно не знаю. А покупать не надо, он бесплатный на 30 дней. 

Самому к сожалению разобраться не получилось с этим, пол дня сегодня сидел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Навскидку - проверьте права на загруженный файл

```
substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($filename)), -4)
```

, попробуйте потестить функцию отдельно(на 2 существующих файлах с правами 0777), проверьте, в конце концов, существование обоих файлов (лого и загруженного, функция **file_exists**).

К слову, насколько я помню, `$arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"]` уже содержит путь, или нет?

Comment: `$arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"]` содержит путь от корня

Comment: Дык путь тогда будет не **`$arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"]['tmp_name']`** (строка-массив? о_О), а **`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"]`**. 
<hr />
**`$arFields["MORE_PHOTO"]`** - это вроде вообще массив. 
<hr />
Короче говоря, почаще пользуйтесь конструкцией `die(var_dump($var, $var2[, ..., $varN]))` с глючащими переменными.

Answer (score 0):

По идее, этот модуль врисовывает логотип в картинку, то есть отображать он ничего не будет, 1 раз запустил скрипт, картинка наложилась, и навечно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это: [самый гибкий и удобный watermark](http://subcoder.ru/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-watermark/).

Answer (score 0):

[Водяной знак (watermark) на PHP](http://sgu.kz/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=3736)